# How to fill DataGridViewComboBoxColumn from a database table column without using datareader

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview

Here is my code:

```
            SqlDataAdapter GridDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
            DataSet GridDataSet = new DataSet();
            GridDataAdapter.Fill(GridDataSet, tbln);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = GridDataSet;
            DataGridViewComboBoxColumn dgvCB = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();

            dataGridView1.DataMember = tbln;
```

Here, I want to fetch data for DataGridViewComboBox from a database table column.

How can I fill the DataGridViewComboBoxColumn without using a DataReader?

Answer (score 0):

You already have the dataset filled, you could just iterate over the row collection if it contains the values that you want the DGVCombo to contain. So, the most straightforward way would be something along the lines of:

```
foreach(DataRow r in GridDataSet.Tables[0].Rows)
{
   dgvCB.Items.Add(r["MyColumn"]);
}
```

Where .Tables[0] has the column("MyColumn") that you are looking for...

Comment: its n argument exception cell value is not valid

Comment: Try r["MyColumn"].ToString()

Answer (score 0):

This should be what you need...

```
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn dgvCB = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
dgvCB.Name = "lastname";
dgvCB.DataSource = tbln;
dgvCB.HeaderText = "Last";
//uncomment this to actually select the value in the combo box 
//dgvCB.DataPropertyName = "lastname";
dgvCB.ValueMember = "lastname";
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(dgvCB);
```